# MySQL nested SELECT too slow

Tags: mysql, select, left-join

I have a script of the following structure:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN pf.info IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM summary s 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, info FROM items GROUP BY id) pf ON s.id=pf.id
GROUP BY s.date
```

What I want is to count those id's which are in 'summary' and present in 'items'. 'items' have same id's repeated several times, that's why I do GROUP BY.

This script works as I want, but it is extremely slow, much slower than just doing straightforward LEFT JOIN (and counting each id several times). This doesn't seem to make sense since I need a smaller subspace of that and it should be easier.

So the question is: how to restructure the query to make it quicker?

Comment: `SELECT id, info FROM items GROUP BY id` --- what `info` is selected with this query? What if some particular `id` has several infos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `count(distinct ...)`:

```
SELECT count(distinct s.id)
FROM summary s 
JOIN items i ON s.id = i.id
```

I don't understand why you are grouping by `s.date` - there's no clue in your question as to why, so if it's not a mistake and you need to group by `date`, use this:

```
SELECT s.date, count(distinct s.id)
FROM summary s 
JOIN items i ON s.id = i.id
GROUP BY s.date
```

Comment: This query doesn't do entirely the same. In original query there could be several rows with the same `s.id` in the result set

Comment: @zerkms then it's not an "id". I'm willing to bet it is a key.

Comment: Thank you, that works. That was easy, sorry for stupid question :)